# How to create generic DbSet table that can be used in linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics, dbset

I have 3 Entity DBSet table => **(Table1, Table2, Table3)**

Three of them have same properties name => **(id, UserName, Role)**

[image: My Function]

**Question:** how do I create a function that can be used for 3 different DbSet table?

Can we create a generic DBSet and access property by typing the string "id" and do the linq query like => **a.("id")** equals **b.PkId** (code above).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"Three of them have same properties name"_ - apply an interface, accept an `IQueryable<TInterface>` as parameter.

Comment: @CodeCaster Hi, thanks for commenting, do you mean create an interface for my function or properties?